# About Mac computer's file permission

Tags: permission

I was trying to install Joomla on my Macbook Air under XAMPP. I successfully installed it, but when I try to open the front-end, I keep getting this `mkdir():permission denied` error.

Two questions raised while I was trying to solve this problem:

1. I noticed when I do `ls -l`, the owner/group of some folders is *`myname`*:`admin`, while those of other folders is `root:admin`. I am the only user of this computer and the *`myname`* user should have all root privileges.

   What I don't understand:

   A. Why when I do `chmod` I had to `sudo chmod`.

   B. Why there are folders with different owner.
2. To solve the problem, I forcefully changed owner/group of all related files and directories to `root:root` and permissions of those to `0777`. But eventually I will have to move this over to a production server and it is not wise to keep the owner and permission like this. Is there any better way to solve the problem while keeping the owner/permission settings as tight as possible?

Comment: You don't tell us where exactly you are installing things and which specific directories you are seeing/changing permissions. You could be on safe ground or you could be about to enter a situation where you erase and reinstall the OS....

Comment: By default it is `/applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs`

Comment: Please could you split this into two separate questions. You will then attract better, more focused, answers to each.

Comment: Go through the install info provided by Joomla first. I remember that it works as long as you follow the instructions closely. (It hurts the ego, I know…)

Comment: BTW Apple has decided that the /Applications folder (and their Apps in it) are pretty much not deletable. Go ahead try and drag "Chess" out of the /Applications folder. Apple is trying to protect you from yourself. Try putting XAMPP in ~/Applications. You will have full control of the directory structure there.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is needed to change permissions of files and folders that the current user account does not have permissions to modify.

In this case, the `chmod myname` required `sudo` because some of the files and folders being modified were owned by `root`.

By default, the first user account is an administrator. This is likely the account you are currently using. Administrator permissions are not equivalent to those of [`root`](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14281). `root` exists above administrator users on OS X.

With regard to how best to deploy Joomla on a production server, this is better [asked in a separate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change permissions and owner of a file, volume or folder is to use BatchMod. Once downloaded from here
http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/
you will have to run the program. It will prompt you to insert the Administrator password to gain Superuser access. Type it discretely and then you will be allowed to select a file. Make sure to tick "Change owner and permission", and then, feel free to change permissions as you wish. You will have to confirm and the process will be extremely quick. This saved my back when trying to gain permissions onto a TimeMachine Backup I had which refused to open.